# Split every character of a word in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Split every character of a word..Such as 
"CAT"=C,A,T

I have been able get the full length of the word..by taking input in a edit text..

```
package com.pack.name;

import android.R.array;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NamtestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText name;
    Button save;
    String sname;
    int pname, i;
    char eachword[];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sname = name.getText().toString();
        pname = sname.length();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + pname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        //for (i = 0; i < pname; i++) {


        }

    }
```

}

Here we take input from the edittext and then by clicking the button it shows the length of the word ...Now what i need to split the word ..i was trying to do this in a for loop...
Help Please .....

Comment: You can get each character with `.charAt(index)`. If you want to split the String into smaller String each contains one character, you can use `.split("")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can do this using **BreakIterator class** with **getCharaterInstance() static method.**

   see this link for more detail:

   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html
2. You can manually do this using `toCharArray()`.

   public void processSong(String word){

   ```
       //Conversion of String to Character Array//

       String s = word.toUpperCase();
       char[] tempArr = s.toCharArray();
       Character[] arr = new Character[tempArr.length];




       for (int i=0,j=0 ; i<tempArr.length ; i++,j++){

           arr[i] = tempArr[j];
       }


       for (Character c : l){

                tempL.add(c);



       }


       Log.d("Vivek-Characters",tempL.toString());
       }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use:

```
eachword = sname.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through them like this:

```
for (char c: sname.toCharArray()) {
    ...
}
```

or just save them

```
char[] chars = sname.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

just call

```java
"CAT".toCharArray();
```

you will get as the result

> [C, A, T]